# How do you add user defined properties/values in to the Android manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-custom-attributes

I want to add a custom attribute / property into the manifest file, and be able to read it at run time. I want to do this so I can customize the app's behavior via these manifest properties. How can this be done?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can add meta-data to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and then read that in your application.

Write the data like so:

```
<meta-data android:value="bar" android:name="foo"></meta-data>
```

And read the data like so:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Object value = (Object)ai.metaData.get("foo");
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Comment: The calls here work perfectly. One thing worth mentioning if other users come across this is that you'll want to wrap this with try/catch PackageManager.NameNotFoundException (especially in Android Studio, this won't even compile without wrapping it).

Answer (score 10):

You can create an empty resource file in res/values and add strings and items (for bool or integer values) to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="foo">bar</string">
    <item name="testint" type="integer">33</item>
    <item name="testbool" type="bool">true</item>
</resources>
```

Alternatively you could simply use a Constants object in which you define your properties as final static variables.

Comment: thanks, would you please show the code needed to read the value of foo from the resource file

Comment: should be 
    getResources().getString(R.string.foo)
    getResources().getInteger(R.integer.testint)
    getResources.getBoolean(R.bool.testbool)

see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html for more details

Comment: Like the idea, easy to get value without any parser

Comment: yes this is an alternative but if you have multi values folder like values-en, values-jp you must define your constants to all strings.xml files. same data in multiple files, I think this is disadvantage in many ways.

Comment: I believe the drawback in the comment above can be relieved by using a base "values" folder with no localization suffix