# How can I access configuration from within Nativescript app

Tags: nativescript

I want to provide configuration settings into my android app without putting them in code, e.g. an API url (so that i can replace them post-build later). Where do I put this (should it go into AndroidManifest.xml?), and how can I retrieve it?

Comment: Have you done any research before coming here to post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794656/where-to-put-the-api-key-resources-meta-data-in-manifest-or-static-variable

Comment: Great, but how do I access this within Nativescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Had to put the meta-data key in Application (not Activity) and then access it as such:

```
const ai = app.android.context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(app.android.context.getPackageName(), 128);
this.apiUrl = ai.metaData.get("apiUrl");
```